# Getting "Invalid message: ERROR Internal Server Error" in some instances when running Selenium Tests on SauceLabs

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, saucelabs, selenium-iedriver

Have been running the selenium test cases against IE 11 browser in SauceLabs VM. For every 1 in 30-40 test cases, I am getting WebdriverException: Invalid message: ERROR Internal Server Error

The UI just gets stuck there, for a couple of minutes, and we get this error for 2-3 test cases, and then again it starts running fine.

Below is the trace:

```
org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: Invalid message: ERROR Internal 
Server Error (WARNING: The server did not provide any stacktrace 
information)
Command duration or timeout: 0 milliseconds
Build info: version: '3.11.0', revision: 'e59cfb3', time: '2018-03- 
11T20:26:55.152Z'
System info: host: 'WSDEL-HPV123-AA', ip: '192.168.21.76', os.name: 'Windows 
10', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '10.0', java.version: '1.8.0_131'
Driver info: org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver
Capabilities {browserAttachTimeout: 0, browserName: internet explorer, 
cssSelectorsEnabled: true, elementScrollBehavior: 0, 
enableElementCacheCleanup: true, enablePersistentHover: false, hasMetadata: 
true, ie.browserCommandLineSwitches: , ie.enableFullPageScreenshot: true, 
ie.ensureCleanSession: true, ie.fileUploadDialogTimeout: 3000, 
ie.forceCreateProcessApi: false, ie.forceShellWindowsApi: false, 
ignoreProtectedModeSettings: true, ignoreZoomSetting: false, 
initialBrowserUrl: about:blank, javascriptEnabled: true, nativeEvents: 
false, pageLoadStrategy: normal, platform: WINDOWS, platformName: WINDOWS, 
requireWindowFocus: false, takesScreenshot: true, unexpectedAlertBehaviour: 
accept, unhandledPromptBehavior: accept, version: 11, 
webdriver.remote.sessionid: 9ea7dfe2a4f04c78b199dc0b572...}
Session ID: 9ea7dfe2a4f04c78b199dc0b572b70f4
```

1. Since it also shows WebdriverException, I worked on my click(assuming that could be the problem as well.) method with proper waits and reloads, and using jsClick now. But still no luck.
2. On reading something about Invalid message: ERROR Internal 
   Server Error on SauceLabs, it says that its a known error and occurs 1 in 1000 tests.

But I am keen to resolve this since we are facing it more often than they suggest.

Environment.

1. IE 11
2. Windows 10
3. Saucelabs Vm
4. Selenium version: 3.11
5. IE driver version: 2.52.0
6. Java

Comment: If you are running tests on SauceLabs, you have an account with them. Why not open a ticket and ask them what the issue is?

Comment: @JeffC , if I would have gotten a satisfactory response from them , I wouldnt have posted it here. -_-